# How do I repair an ubuntu install with apparmor running forever at startup?

Tags: boot, upgrade, apparmor

I tried to upgrade an Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS install to 23.04 last night.  Upon reboot, the system will hang trying to start AppArmor.  I found a few posts in the past about disabling app armor from starting in recovery mode.  I also can't boot into recovery mode (same behavior).  I've tried systemd.mask=apparmor.service on grub screen with recovery mode as suggested on old threads with no luck.  When I say it hangs, I let it go overnight and it ran for 9 hours with no end in sight.

I was thinking about booting an ubuntu installer on a flash drive and then trying to repair that way.  I thought about trying to chroot the file system on the SSD and see if I can cleanup some old apps and make sure everything got updated.  Is that the right approach?  Is there a way to disable AppArmor from the mounted filesystem so it doesn't startup?

I saw two warnings during the install about samba and ntpd config files recommending a reboot, but nothing else that seemed out of place.

I did have a fair number of snaps and one flatpak installed on this system going into it.

Comment: "*tried to upgrade an Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS install to 23.04*" The question should include the steps you used for this, as there is no supported one-step method to accomplish it.

Comment: Recovery mode has the exact same behavior as a regular boot.  App Armor runs forever.

Comment: There is one currently supported upgrade path from 22.04; to the next release which is Ubuntu 22.10.  There is **no supported** upgrade path currently from 22.04 to 23.04; so please clarify how you upgraded, as you're outside of the *supported* & fully tested upgrade paths.

Comment: I upgraded using this guide. https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-22-04-to-ubuntu-23-04

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, I had to boot off the ubuntu installer USB image for 23.04, mount the file system the OS is installed on with sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt, run chroot /mnt, edit /etc/resolv.conf to add a valid DNS server,

sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade;  sudo apt dist-upgrade

Then I disabled AppArmor sudo systemctl disable apparmor.service

After rebooting, the system came up fine.

Comment: Does AppArmor work properly now when re-enabled?

Comment: It didn't initially.  I had to reinstall app armor and several of it's dependencies, remove some old configs from previous installs, and reinstall snap related stuff to get it back.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. After several hours of research, trial and error, what did the trick was clearing the apt cache and removing apparmor.

Clearing apt cache

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo rm *
```

Removing apparmor

```
sudo apt remove apparmor
```

Comment: Be very aware of the potential consequences of removing AppArmor. I do not consider this a good option, as removing AppArmor leaves your system in a seriously vulnerable state.